# Shell Script to parse/retrieve a string found after another string/match

Tags: string, parsing, shell, sed

The shell script will be passed a string of arguments. The position of the key/value I am looking to parse out may change over time, i.e. it may come before or after another key at any time so parsing between two keys wouldn't be an option.

I am looking to parse the domain key out of a string like this:

```
maxpark 0 maxsub n domain sample.foo maxlst n max_defer_fail_percentage user oli force no_cache_update 0 maxpop n maxaddon 0 locale en contactemail
```

The key would be "domain" the value would be "sample.foo". The domain key could have more than one '.' in it so I would need to grab the entire domain key.

I am not the best with regular expressions but I imagine using 'sed' is what I'm going to need to do.

I am accessing this full string using $*, if I could simply reference the key by accessing $DOMAIN that would be great, but since my only option is to access based on position, $3, and the position could change, that isn't an option

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using PERL.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my %OPTS = @ARGV;

open(FILE, "</var/named/$OPTS{'domain'}.db") || die "File not found";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

my @newlines;
foreach(@lines) {
   $_ =~ s/$LOCAL_IP/$PUBLIC_IP/g;
   push(@newlines,$_);
}

open(FILE, ">/var/named/$OPTS{'domain'}.db") || die "File not found";
print FILE @newlines;
close(FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do have perl, just use this one-liner from your shell script.

```
domain=$( echo $* | perl -ne '/domain\s([^\s]+)\s/ and print "$1"' )
```

Or if you'd rather just do it with `sed`:

```
domain=$( echo $* | sed 's/.*\<domain \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/' )
```